# SQL Server upgrade advisor reserved keyword warning - Can't find keyword!

Tags: sql-server-2008, upgrade, sql-server-2000

I am running [SQL Server 2008 Upgrade Advisor tool](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=11455) on a SQL Server 2000 DB, and the final report shows an error:

> Database Server,"PreUpgrade",
>   
> "After upgrade, new reserved keywords cannot be used as identifiers",
>   
> "Upgrade Advisor detected an idetifier with name **Merge**",
>   
> "Source Type: Database","Database: **Domus**","Object Name: **crosstab**","Object Type: P ",
>   
> "Key Word: **pivot**"

The message is a bit ambiguos for me.... Using the [following script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27361062/367032), I have searched the keyword 'pivot' and 'Merge' in all tables, however there are no results.

Should I ignore this error?

Comment: The error message already calls out that you have the keyword `pivot` in stored procedure `crosstab`. Just view the source for that procedure and search for `pivot`. The script you referenced searches for data in tables, not object definitions.

Comment: The script you pointed at is looking for strings in columns, which is just user data and wouldn't cause a problem for any upgrade advisor. You need to look at the definition of that procedure, e.g. `USE Domus; SELECT OBJECT_DEFINITION(OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.crosstab'));`

Answer (score 0):

```
-- Search for "Merge" identifier in all objects
DECLARE @IdentifierToSearch NVARCHAR(128) = 'Merge';

-- Search in tables
SELECT TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE COLUMN_NAME = @IdentifierToSearch;

-- Search in views, functions, procedures, and triggers
SELECT OBJECT_NAME(object_id) AS ObjectName, definition
FROM sys.sql_modules
WHERE definition LIKE '%' + @IdentifierToSearch + '%';
```